# Script works for Computers but won't work in mobile platforms such as iPhone...code included

Tags: jquery, iphone, ajax, dom, compatibility

### Okay so I got my page up and running and grabbing JSON and outputting it with no problems on my browsers such as Safari, Google Chrome, and Firefox. Problem is the site doesn't work on iPhone of Android. I am guessing the DOM maybe different? As my script doesn't work for them.

Taking advice from a fellow user I changed alot to Jquery. Still having same problem though....
Updated code as follows:

```
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script>
function games(){


$.ajax({
    url: "http://allencoded.com/test3.php",
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function (data) {

    var fetchTeam = $("#team").val(); //value from selection
    var homeTeams = [];//home Teams
    var visitorTeams = [];//visitor teams
    var dayPlayed = [];//day of the game ex.Mon
    var homeTeamFull = [];
    var visitorTeamFull = [];
    var gameTime = [];
    var quarter = [];
    var visitorScore = [];
    var homeScore= [];



    for (var i =0; i < data.gms.length; i++){
        homeTeams[i]=data.gms[i].h }

    for (var i =0; i < data.gms.length; i++){
        visitorTeams[i]=data.gms[i].v }     

    for (var i = 0; i < data.gms.length; i++) {
        dayPlayed[i]=data.gms[i].d}

    for (var i = 0; i < data.gms.length; i++) {
        homeTeamFull[i]=data.gms[i].hnn}

    for (var i = 0; i < data.gms.length; i++) {
        visitorTeamFull[i]=data.gms[i].vnn}

    for (var i = 0; i < data.gms.length; i++) {
        gameTime[i]=data.gms[i].t}

    for (var i = 0; i < data.gms.length; i++) {
        quarter[i]=data.gms[i].q}

    for (var i = 0; i < data.gms.length; i++) {
        homeScore[i]=data.gms[i].hs}

    for (var i = 0; i < data.gms.length; i++) {
        visitorScore[i]=data.gms[i].vs}




    //for statements to get team user team...

    for(i=0; i<homeTeams.length; i++)
    {if (homeTeams[i] == fetchTeam || visitorTeams[i]==fetchTeam)
        {
        $("span#hometeam").html(homeTeamFull[i]);
        $("span#homescore").html(homeScore[i]);
        $("span#awayteam").html(visitorTeamFull[i]);
        $("span#awayscore").html(visitorScore[i]);
        $("span#gametime").html(quarter[i]);

        }
    }

}   
     });

}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#body{
    background-color: #7f007f;
}

#wrapper {

}
#header {
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    line-height:28px;
    text-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,.2) 0 1px 1px;
    }
#hometeam {
    min-width: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    color: #FFF;
    line-height:28px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
#homescore {
    min-width: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 28px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#awayteam {
    width: 200px;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    color: #FFF;
    line-height:28px;
    padding-left: 200px;
}
#awayscore {
    width: 200px;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    color: #FFF;
    line-height:28px;
    padding-left: 200px;
}
#formselect {
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
    line-height:35px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
#gametime {
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
</head>

<body id="body">
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">NFL Score Zone</div>
  <div id="formselect"><form id="teamSelect"><select name="team" id="team">
    <option value="ARI">Arizona Cardinals</option>
    <option value="ATL">Atlanta Falcons</option>
    <option value="BAL">Baltimore Ravens</option>
    <option value="BUF">Buffalo Bills</option>
    <option value="CAR">Carolina Panthers</option>
    <option value="CHI">Chicago Bears</option>
    <option value="CIN">Cincinnati Bengals</option>
    <option value="CLE">Cleveland Browns</option>
    <option value="DAL">Dallas Cowboys</option>
    <option value="DEN">Denver Broncos</option>
    <option value="DET">Detroit Lions</option>
    <option value="GB">Green Bay Packers</option>
    <option value="HOU">Houston Texans</option>
    <option value="IND">Indianapolis Colts</option>
    <option value="JAC">Jacksonville Jaguars</option>
    <option value="KC">Kansas City Chiefs</option>
    <option value="MIA">Miami Dolphins</option>
    <option value="MIN">Minnesota Vikings</option>
    <option value="NE">New England Patriots</option>
    <option value="NO">New Orleans Saints</option>
    <option value="NYG">New York Giants</option>
    <option value="NYJ">New York Jets</option>
    <option value="OAK">Oakland Raiders</option>
    <option value="PHI">Philadelphia Eagles</option>
    <option value="PIT">Pittsburgh Steelers</option>
    <option value="SD">San Diego Chargers</option>
    <option value="SF">San Francisco 49ers</option>
    <option value="SEA">Seattle Seahawks</option>
    <option value="STL">St. Louis Rams</option>
    <option value="TB">Tampa Bay Buccaneers</option>
    <option value="TEN">Tennessee Titans</option>
    <option value="WAS">Washington Redskins</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="submit" onClick="games();"/>
    </form></div>
  <center><span id="gametime">Game Time Remaining</span></center>  
  <center><span id="hometeam"></span><span id="awayteam"></span></center>
   <center><span id="homescore"></span><span id="awayscore"></span></center>
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Problematic script is not population fields:

```
<script>
function games(){


$.ajax({
    url: "http://allencoded.com/test3.php",
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function (data) {

    var fetchTeam = $("#team").val(); //value from selection
    var homeTeams = [];//home Teams
    var visitorTeams = [];//visitor teams
    var dayPlayed = [];//day of the game ex.Mon
    var homeTeamFull = [];
    var visitorTeamFull = [];
    var gameTime = [];
    var quarter = [];
    var visitorScore = [];
    var homeScore= [];



    for (var i =0; i < data.gms.length; i++){
        homeTeams[i]=data.gms[i].h }

    for (var i =0; i < data.gms.length; i++){
        visitorTeams[i]=data.gms[i].v }     

    for (var i = 0; i < data.gms.length; i++) {
        dayPlayed[i]=data.gms[i].d}

    for (var i = 0; i < data.gms.length; i++) {
        homeTeamFull[i]=data.gms[i].hnn}

    for (var i = 0; i < data.gms.length; i++) {
        visitorTeamFull[i]=data.gms[i].vnn}

    for (var i = 0; i < data.gms.length; i++) {
        gameTime[i]=data.gms[i].t}

    for (var i = 0; i < data.gms.length; i++) {
        quarter[i]=data.gms[i].q}

    for (var i = 0; i < data.gms.length; i++) {
        homeScore[i]=data.gms[i].hs}

    for (var i = 0; i < data.gms.length; i++) {
        visitorScore[i]=data.gms[i].vs}




    //for statements to get team user team...

    for(i=0; i<homeTeams.length; i++)
    {if (homeTeams[i] == fetchTeam || visitorTeams[i]==fetchTeam)
        {
        $("span#hometeam").html(homeTeamFull[i]);
        $("span#homescore").html(homeScore[i]);
        $("span#awayteam").html(visitorTeamFull[i]);
        $("span#awayscore").html(visitorScore[i]);
        $("span#gametime").html(quarter[i]);

        }
    }

}   
     });

}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the site?

Comment: added link at bottom of the post...http://allencoded.com/ahindex.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's working fine. iPad 1.4.5 and Android gingerbread.

Comment: Just tried it on my iphone and on my brothers android device...both are updated to latest firmwares. It did not work

Comment: Is it the document.getElementById("team").value I know iphoen and android use a different style selector...don't know if that matters

Comment: seems to be working for me as well... not sure what the issue you're seeing is.

Comment: what are you guys testing in? I am using an actual iphone updated to latest and greatest firmware?

Comment: I got it working...Not sure what the problem was I had to not only clear the cache, but browsing history, and cookies. Then I restarted my phone and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because you're not defining the `type` of the script? Have you tried the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//code here
</script>
```

For the tags instead of just `<script></script>`? Sometimes when you add the `type="text/javascript` it makes the scripts work because the browser knows what type of script it is when you add that in.

**Update:**

It is actually working for me on my iPhone with the newest firmware installed (iOS 4.3.5) on Mobile Safari:

[image: iPhone Screenshot]

Comment: Oh ok. Hmm, that's weird. Have you tried using jQuery? (**much easier** than traditional JavaScript.) jQuery works for me on my iPhone.

Comment: *embarassingly* I am not up to snuff on jQuery to much :(

Comment: Oh, well instead of `document.getElementById('id')` in jQuery it is `$('#id')` and when if you want it to fade in, for example, you would us this: `$('#id').fadeIn();` jQuery is actually _easier_ than traditional JavaScript. You can learn more about jQuery here: http://jquery.com/

Comment: Converted it over to Jquery still having problems...like jQuery though and was able to pick up the selector stuff pretty quickly!

Comment: I'm glad you picked it up quickly :) As for the problem with the script, I don't know why it isn't working for you, as it is working for me on my iPhone. See my edited answer above, with a screenshot...

Comment: I got it working. Don't know why it wouldn't work at first, but it is now. Now all I have to do is tidy up the code and make it look pretty instead of drabby and purple. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad you got it working. Good luck on it, I'm sure it'll be great when you're done! :)